# How many amp can arduino take

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Im currently trying to get an electric signal from arduino, its 5v and 1amp that i get from a powersupply.
I want to input that signal into an arduino pin, lets say pin 4.
The main powersource from my arduino is via usb, but the 5v signal is from an external device.

I just want to know the number of time that signal became active, like a switch.

As far as i know arduino can take only .04amp from 5v.

Is there anyway i can reduce the current?
Anyway to obtain the value of a resistor to make it less dangerous for my arduino?

Comment: Hello, Jorge. I suggest you try asking on the forum specific for arduino, also because StackOverflow is for programming questions only. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/
Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a very common application for Arduino!

You can give your Arduino some additional protection by placing a 10kOhm resistor between the Arduino analog pin you wish to use and the positive voltage output of the power supply.

If you're worried that the voltage could increase above 5V, you can protect your arduino with a simple voltage divider using two resistors. There's a detailed tutorial for this approach here: https://startingelectronics.org/articles/arduino/measuring-voltage-with-arduino/ Here's a simplified circuit diagram with a voltage divider that reduces voltage 11 fold - making voltages up to 55V safe to measure (where the battery could be replaced by your power supply):

[image]

For your code, you can use analogread() to read the voltage of the pin. If you wired it correctly, it should return near 0 when the powersupply is at 0, and 1026 or thereabouts if it is at 5v (or whatever the maximum value your voltage divider is designed for).  Here is an example to get you started :

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/

If you need any support with your code to count the number of times the voltage goes high, post that as a separate question along with the code you have so far.